# How to call class methods with there properites dynamically in PHP

Tags: php

Hullo Geeks, am develoving my own PHP simple MVC for my php projects with SMARTY as the default templating engine.

However, i have run into a state where i need to load Model classes in a controller class and access them anywhere the controller classes just like how Codeigniter does it.

The expected results is

//Auth class in controller folder (Route)

```
class Auth extends Controller{
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("Ashan_model");
    $this->load->model("Auth_model");
   }

  function auth() {
    $this->model->Auth_model->login();
  }
 }
```

//Controller Class

```
class Controller {
  public $load; //Loader class
  function __construct() {
    //parent::__construct();
    //Loading models
    $this->load = new Load();
    $this->model = $this->load->__model();
  }
}
```

//Load class

```
class Load {
   public $model = [];
   function __construct()
    {
    //parent::__construct();
   }

  public function model($class) {
    try {
        include_once("./models/" . $class . ".php");
        $this->model[] = new $class();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->class_load_error("Caught an exception".$e->getMessage());
    }
    print_r($this->model);
}

 public function __model() {
    print_r($this->model);
  }
}
```

I need help on how i can go over it. For i need to load libraries, helpers as well using Load class and call them anywhere in my routed classes

Comment: Instead of going down the "CI way" regarding loading dependencies, I would recommend that you read up on [dependency injection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-dependency-injection-in-php#:~:text=Object%20Oriented%20ProgrammingPHPProgramming,at%20runtime%20and%20compile%20time.). It's a very common way to load dependencies which makes your code very testable and makes it easy to swap them out .

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what is the "CI way"? OP: I think you need an autoloader([PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)) and for managing dependencies a container([PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/meta/)).

Comment: @Pilan - Having methods for loading dependencies in the classes, like  `$this->load->model('xxx')` etc.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ah I see, the [C]ode[I]gniter way I suppose? :D

Comment: @Pilan - Yes. CI = CodeIgniter :-)